# angular page blank at localhost

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn angular from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. But when I am accessing localhost:4200, my web page is blank.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the web page, but still, it's the same.

Comment: Check your console (normally F12) in the window to see the error.

Comment: Try using the Angular CLI to generate your code instead: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IE, you need to open polyfills.ts file under src folder and uncomment below lines

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```